# Solving matrices equations using invert matrices properties and determinant properties.

Tags: matrices

I have a trouble to find matrices P.
$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4 \\ 5&-2\end{bmatrix}.P.\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Please help me, to find matrices $P$ using determinant and invert matrices property. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to solve

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4 \\ 5&-2\end{bmatrix}\cdot P\cdot\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\iff P\cdot\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4 \\ 5&-2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

For the inverse use the formula [**here**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html) and then indicating with $v_1$ and $v_2$ the column of $P$ we have

$$P\cdot\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}=3v_1+2v_2$$